# How to install glibmm-2.68 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, c++, pkg-config

I am trying to install GTK4/GTKMM4 for C++ on Ubuntu 22.04 but I am stuck on step 3, possibly step 2.

I am following these instructions:
https://terminalroot.com/how-to-install-gtkmm-4-on-ubuntu-2204/

Here are the steps if you don’t want to click on the link:

**Step 1:** `sudo apt install build-essential git g++ autotools-dev libgtkmm-3.0-dev \`

`libgtkmm-3.0-doc mm-common libgtk-4-bin \`

`libgtk-4-common libgtk-4-dev libgtk-4-doc pkg-config`

that worked without errors

**Step 2:** `wget ftp://ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/gnome/sources/libsigc++/3.0/libsigc++-3.0.7.tar.xz`

`tar Jxvf libsigc++-3.0.7.tar.xz`

`cd libsigc++-3.0.7/`

`./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local`

`make`

`sudo make install`

The make worked without errors

Here is sudo make install, installing part (note the filenames: sigc++-3.0.pc and libsigc-3.0.so.2.99.1):

```
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/sigc++-3.0/include/sigc++config.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/sigc++-3.0.pc
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/sigc++-3/sigc++-3Config.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/sigc++-3/sigc++-3ConfigVersion.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/sigc++-3/sigc++-3Targets.cmake
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/cmake/sigc++-3/sigc++-3Targets-noconfig.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/connection.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/limit_reference.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/functors
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/functors/ptr_fun.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/functors/mem_fun.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/functors/functor_trait.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/functors/slot_base.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/functors/.libs
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/functors/.deps
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/functors/slot.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/functors/functors.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/trackable.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/retype_return.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/.libs
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/CMakeFiles
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/CMakeFiles/sigc-3.0.dir
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/CMakeFiles/sigc-3.0.dir/functors
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/bind_return.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/sigc++.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/signal.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/weak_raw_ptr.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/signal_base.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/visit_each.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/.deps
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/member_method_trait.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/reference_wrapper.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/adaptors
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/adaptors/adaptor_trait.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/adaptors/retype.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/adaptors/tuple_visitor_visit_each.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/adaptors/exception_catch.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/adaptors/compose.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/adaptors/adapts.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/adaptors/adaptor_base.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/adaptors/retype_return.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/adaptors/bind_return.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/adaptors/bound_argument.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/adaptors/track_obj.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/adaptors/hide.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/adaptors/adaptors.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/adaptors/bind.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/type_traits.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/tuple-utils
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/tuple-utils/tuple_end.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/tuple-utils/tuple_transform_each.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/tuple-utils/tuple_for_each.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/tuple-utils/tuple_cdr.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/tuple-utils/tuple_start.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/slot.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/sigc++-3.0/sigc++/bind.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libsigc-3.0.so.2.99.1
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libsigc-3.0.so.0
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libsigc-3.0.so
```

**Step 3:** `wget https://download.gnome.org/sources/glibmm/2.68/glibmm-2.68.2.tar.xz`

`tar Jxvf glibmm-2.68.2.tar.xz`

`cd glibmm-2.68.2/`

`./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr`

`make`

`sudo make install`

running `./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr` which gave an error that it could not find sigc++. It suggested setting PKG_CONFIG_PATH. somewhere it asked for the .pc file, so I found the sigc++-3.0.pc line from step 2 and set:

`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/sigc++-3.0.pc`

then I re-ran `./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr`

Here is the interesting part:

```
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for sigc++-3.0 >= 3.0.0 glib-2.0 >= 2.63.0 gobject-2.0 >= 2.63.0 gmodule-2.0 >= 2.63.0... no
configure: error: Package requirements (sigc++-3.0 >= 3.0.0 glib-2.0 >= 2.63.0 gobject-2.0 >= 2.63.0 gmodule-2.0 >= 2.63.0) were not met:

Requested 'sigc++-3.0 >= 3.0.0' but version of libsigc++ is 2.99.1
```

why did sigc add the 2.99?  “-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libsigc-3.0.so.2.99.1”

Comment: AFAIK the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` should contain the *path to* the file, not the file itself so `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`. However that should be in the default path anyhow - as you can verify via `pkg-config --variable=pc_path pkg-config`

Comment: That worked, thank you.